# Error while trying to send a mail in java

Tags: java, connection

I developed a project for automatically sending mails from a specific account using 
javax.mail service. I developed and tested the application and it seem to work properly at the time but now I get a connection error when I start it.

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I don't know what happened since I first developed it, I didn't modify the code at all.

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't change the code at all, you might want to try running the project on a different network. Sometimes certain networks block the frameworks. Also if this isn't working try disabling the antivirus, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the antivirus and/or extensions are disable and I suggest you to use a gmail account and enable access for less secure apps :
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps